# Check if Ansible pipelining is enabled / working

Tags: ansible, pipelining

Ansible has the ability to work faster when pipelining is enabled. However there are some requirements to make this work. Pipelinging must be enabled in ansible.cfg or in the inventory-file and requiretty must be dissabled.

I already checked -vvvv, nothing showed up concering 'pipelining'. Also, I do not notice any difference in speed.

Because of all this I would like to know if: **is there a way to verify Ansible is using the pipelining ability?**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To check if pipelining is in use, call: `ansible test-server -vvv -m shell -a 'echo ok'`.

If you see only **one** `SSH: EXEC ssh` record with something like `/bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/python && sleep 0'`, then pipelining is in use.

If you see three to five `SSH: EXEC ssh`/`SSH: EXEC sftp`/`PUT` records, executing `command.py` from tmp path, then pipelining mode is not active.

Comment: Make sure pipelining = True is defined under ssh_connection and not defaults.

Comment: Weirdly, I had to put it under `defaults` for it to be recognized, _not_ `ssh_connection`. I just verified that pipeline is working using the method described in this answer, and by running `ansible-config dump | grep PIPE`. My `ansible --version` returns `2.11.6`. Maybe there was a regression?

Comment: With pipelining enabled `copy` is still *extremely* slow. To copy a single file I see x10 "SSH: EXEC"  in the ouput and x8 with pipelining enabled. One or two of those are warm up stuff but most are done for *every* file if your copying a directory! You can use synchronize but copy should still not be this slow.